# Kendo UI Tabstrip dependencies

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/olIveTIS), and it contain tab1 & tab2, on each tab have a table grid. It's possible to create tabstrip dependency based on an `id` in tab1?

For example in `Tab1` I selected a name, then in `Tab2` it will fetch an `id` and display data based on related id.

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/olIveTIS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the value to prefilter the second grid

```
 dataSource: {    
    filter: { field: "YourColumn", operator: "equals", value: x}
}
```

And update the 2nd grid

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```